# ElasticSearch services own logs

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I Installed ELK (ElasticSearch + Kibana + Logstash) on Ubuntu machines following the steps described in https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-logstash-and-kibana-to-centralize-and-visualize-logs-on-ubuntu-14-04 .

All works fine when using /var/log/syslog file as a log source. If I change to another file, no data appear in Kibana interface. I tried to debug the applications but no helpful information was found in:

**/var/log/elasticsearch

/var/log/logstash/logstash.log

/var/log/syslog**

Does anybody know where can I find detailed logging for ElasticSearch, Logstash and Logstash-Forwarder beside previous specified files?

TLDR;
Where ElasticSearch, Logstash and Logstash-Forwarder output their logs beside /var/log/elasticsearch; /var/log/logstash/logstash.log; /var/log/syslog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to set up a handler in LogStash to consume ElasticSearch's logs. I threw together a Pattern to help out with this (detailed below). Something like:

```
input {
  file {
    type => "elasticsearch-log"
    path => ["/var/log/elasticsearch/*.log"]
    sincedb_path => "/opt/logstash/sincedb-access"
    discover_interval => 10
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "elasticsearch-log" {
    grok {
      match       => [ "message", "%{ELASTICSEARCHLOG}" ]
    }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    host => "localhost"
  }
}
```

The pattern file would go in `/opt/logstash/patterns/elasticsearch`

```
ELASTICSEARCHTIME \[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\]
ELASTICSEARCHLEVEL \[%{LOGLEVEL:level}\s+\]
ELASTICSEARCHSERVICE \[%{DATA:service}\s+\]
ELASTICSEARCHVERSION \[%{DATA:version}\]
ELASTICSEARCHLOG %{ELASTICSEARCHTIME}%{ELASTICSEARCHLEVEL}%{ELASTICSEARCHSERVICE} %{ELASTICSEARCHVERSION} %{GREEDYDATA:mymessage}
```

Comment: I don't want to parse ELK generated logs. I want to know where they hide :D. But thank you for the pattern

Answer (score 0):

That is the location of the logs, not much detailed information to be found in there regarding missing entries into elasticsearch.

You can do the following to see if you are passing logs into ES:

Check the permissions on the other log sources you are using, ensure logstash has permissions to read these files.

Add this output to your logstash config:

```
output {
   stdout { codec => rubydebug }
```

Run logstash from the commandline, see if you can see logs getting parsed:

```
bin/logstash -f logstash.conf -l logstash.log -e
```

Check the ES count api to see if the number of documents is increasing in ES:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_cat/count?v'
```